# Did I copy the class instance or the class handler here?

Tags: python, class, handler

I want to sort class handlers by class properties.
First I generate a list of class handlers, the following 5 lines are processed in a while loop.

```py
# here a serial no was entered and validity checked
if snr_ok == True:
    device_list.append(Device(snr, prop_list))
    logging.info ("Added serial number " + snr + " with properties " + prop_list)
else: 
    pass
    
    """Group all instances of by property (which is a gas type)"""    
    calibration_gases = {'He':[], 'O2':[], 'N':[], 'Ar':[]}                    
    for gas in list(calibration_gases):
        for dev in device_list:
            if gas in dev.get_gaslist(): # get_gaslist returns a list of strings with some of the gases
                calibration_gases[gas].**append(dev)**
    print (calibration_gases)
```

By grouping the `dev` elements by gas type I add them to the calibration_gases dict.
My question is:
Is dev a copy of the class instance or is it a copy of the class handler?
Or spoken in C: Is dev a pointer to the class instance or is it a copy of the class itself?

Comment: You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. Python doesn't have a call-by-value/call-by-reference distinction, instead using a call-by-object-identity paradigm. Unless you're explicitly copying something (for example using slicing, `obj.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy`), it doesn't happen.

What gets added to `calibration_gases[gas]` *is the same object* that can be found in `device_list`.

By the way, instead of `for gas in list(calibration_gases):` you could simply do `for gas in calibration_gases:`. Even better, you could do:

```
for gas, devices in calibration_gases.items():
    for dev in device_list:
        if gas in dev.get_gaslist():
            devices.append(dev)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, thats what I was hoping